# What should I know as prerequisites before studying Dirichlet/Beta regression

Tags: references, beta-distribution, dirichlet-distribution

Dirichlet regression for compositional data is described e.g. [here](http://epub.wu.ac.at/4077/1/Report125.pdf)

But I do not quite understand the theory, even if I could probably manage to fit some models in R. What do I need to know before I can fully understand the theoretical underpinnings?

The link above states that it develops a "GLM - like" framework, so is that it? E.g., McCullagh's book? Or is there some other topic (multivariate analysis, maybe?) that is needed?

Comment: Beta regression is almost-GLM, so you need to understand beta distribution and the general ideas about GLM's.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could start reading about the beta regression first and then move to the multivariate case (Dirichlet). Ferrari has written a lot of papers on beta regression and many of them are open access (google them and see).

The GLM framework comes from the fact that you can use the logit link to model the mean of the distribution (beta or Dirichlet). There are more papers about  Dirichlet regression and Dirichlet distribution (again open access).

In the Dirichlet regression, one variable is chosen as the baseline, essentially, and the regression takes place with one variable less. 
logistic regression uses the same link as beta regression and multinomial logistic regression uses the same link as Dirichlet regression.